# Android intent not being sent

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase auth in my app. I'm checking if the user is authenticated on my MainActivity just as explained on the Firebase docs and the Udacity course.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null){
        loadLogIn();
    }
    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (user == null){
                loadLogIn();
            }
        }
    };

private void loadLogIn(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    //Flags prevent user from returning to MainActivity when pressing back button
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I step through the code with the debugger, everything works well, the user is null so the loadLogIn method is called, which sends the intent, but Login Activity never opens, and I get a crash because it keeps executing code that needs the user to be authenticated. The onCreate method if my login activity is never called. I cannot understand why the intent is not executing/ what is stopping it. This had been tested and worked perfectly previously.

When the intent line is executed I get the following output on the console :

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.tobias.run time:2369840341
```

This is my manifest if it helps :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".app.RunApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".app.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".editor.EditorActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".app.MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/LoginTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".app.MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".login.NewAccountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/LoginTheme" />

    <activity android:name=".login.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/LoginTheme"/>
</application>
```

This issue first appeared when I tried to sign out from my app calling

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

the user signed out, but the intent was not sent, which left the app in an invalid state, and then it crashed seconds after trying to execute code that required a user. It was not the first time I had signed out of the app, I have done it multiple times and it worked.

This is a weird issue, I hope someone can help me find the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to put your private `loadLogIn()` method outside `onCreate()` method with public modifier... This issue is arising may due to inaccessibility of `loadLogIn()` method inside anonymous class declaration.

Comment: @jackjay good idea I added it to my code but it's not the issue. The `loadLogIn()` is getting called when it needs to, but the intent does nothing.

Comment: finish the current activity and return in the nullcheck, that will prevent the crash. Can you share your LoginActivity?

Comment: @linxy what do you mean about finishing the activity? Also my LoginActivity is very simple, all of it not related to the issue. I can still add it if it helps, but  Login Activity `onCreate` is never called.

Comment: did u try clearing flags and just opening activity without flags.. ??

Comment: @aalappatel yes, nothing changed.

Comment: where is the `authListener`var getting accessed ?? I mean does your code goes inside the `loadLogin` method ??

Comment: @aalappatel Yes, as explained `loadLogin` does get called when it has to. Authstate listener is called when the auth state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
                //...
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
               //...
```

**Solution:**

```
              //...    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
             //...
```

When you use `setFlags` you are replacing the old flags... when you use `addFlags` you are appending new flags. Remember, a `flag` is just a integer which is power of two... in binary, flags look like this: 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc... (which in this case are 1, 2, 4, 8). So, what `addFlags` does is appending the integer you pass using the `|` operator.